# (Terraform) BigQuery Job misses IAM permissions, which have been granted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam, cloud-document-ai

I read [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/add-gen-ai-to-your-apps-with-bigquery-and-document-ai-integration/) blogpost about the recently published Document AI - BigQuery Integration. I want to configure this setup completly using terraform.
An important step in the blog post is the configuration of BigQuery remote models (see screenshot 1).

[image]

Since there is no extra Terraform resource for this (as far as I know), I want to create these models using a BigQuery job.

The simplified terraform I have written looks like this:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset" {
  dataset_id  = "my_dataset"
  project     = "<PROJECT_ID>"
  location    = "EU"
}

resource "google_bigquery_connection" "connection" {
  connection_id = "my-connection"
  project       = "<PROJECT_ID>"
  location      = "EU"
  cloud_resource {}
}

# This grants the previous connection IAM role access to the bucket.
resource "google_project_iam_member" "connection_permission_grant" {
  for_each = toset([
    "roles/storage.objectViewer",
    "roles/documentai.viewer",
  ])
  role     = each.key
  project  = "<PROJECT_ID>"
  member   = "serviceAccount:${google_bigquery_connection.connection.cloud_resource[0].service_account_id}"
}

# create a remote model to register DocAI processor in BigQuery
resource "google_bigquery_job" "job" {
  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.connection_permission_grant,
  ]
  
  job_id   = "my-register-model-job"

  project  = "<PROJECT_ID>"
  location = "EU"

  labels = {}

  query {
    query = <<EOT
      CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `${google_bigquery_dataset.dataset.dataset_id}.my-remote-model`
      REMOTE WITH CONNECTION `${google_bigquery_connection.connection.id}`
      OPTIONS (
        remote_service_type='CLOUD_AI_DOCUMENT_V1',
        document_processor='<PROCESSOR_ID>'
      );
    EOT

    default_dataset {
      dataset_id = "my_dataset"
      project_id = "<PROJECT_ID>"
    }
    create_disposition = ""
    write_disposition = ""
  }
}
```

First I create a connection, which I then give the role "role/documentai.viewer".
Then I create a BigQuery job that uses the connection to create remote models.

All resources are created successfully, but the job returns an error (see screenshot 2).

[image]

Allegedly the service account is missing the "roles/documentai.viewer" role.
However, if I now search for the service account in IAM, this authorization is displayed (see screenshot 3).

[image]

How can this be? Is there a synchronization problem here? Apparently the job is executed before the authorization could be successfully assigned ...
If I redeploy the job with a new job ID after the initial terraform apply (i.e. the service account has already been created), everything works as expected and the models are created correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help!

br, Brian

Comment: 2 Things: Firstly, it could take time to propagate permission. That's why it works only at the second run. Secondly, Terraform is infra as code tools. And you use it to run a query? A post process job that simple execute the query, with bq for instance, would be a better design

Comment: I use the query to create BigQuery remote models, which I use in further steps to create scheduled queries and to provide an analysis pipeline. I know it's not the nicest way, but unfortunately there is currently no Terraform resource for creating remote models.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the assignment of permissions is not "waited for" before Terraform creates the job. After all, I have defined a "depends_on" in the job resource. 
A similar structure is used by Google when creating an [object table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/object-tables?hl=de#terraform) and here the assignment of permissions and the subsequent creation of the table works.

Comment: I would have assumed that Terraform would have waited for the IAM policy changed to have become "effective" but apparently not as illustrated in this 2018 issue ... https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/1131

I'm curious if this is still a thing?  It seems to open up an issue with ANY IAM Policy change that precedes an operation that depends on it.

See also ... https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/access-change-propagation

Workarounds seem to be "sleep for a fixed period" to "improve" the likelihood of eventual consistency becoming effective.